# Git way to ignore code change but keep tracking

Tags: git

I know that exists this way to untrack changes to file
with
`git update-index --skip-worktree FILE` but
I need to completely forget one particular commit / or changes to
file and then still be allowed to track new changes.
With skip worktree I just disable tracking changes completely,
then I can enable it and at the end I have back my changes which
I wanted have untracked in git but included in file. I just need
save change to file (its windows path problem) but won't remove
file from git to utracked. I don't need gitignore and I don't need
`git rm --cached`.

I won't make commit whenever I change paths with sed,
from Unix to Windows and backwards. I don't have cross platform solution to path problem but mantaining two version of program. I want to have the same git changes except the path commit but need to save different paths on Unix.

Comment: Please explain the original context, it is interesting to understand why would you need to do such an operation.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't offer a way to do that.  From [the Git FAQ entry for this issue](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIignorechangestoatrackedfile):

> Git doesn’t provide a way to do this. The reason is that if Git needs to overwrite this file, such as during a checkout, it doesn’t know whether the changes to the file are precious and should be kept, or whether they are irrelevant and can safely be destroyed. Therefore, it has to take the safe route and always preserve them.
>
> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.
>
> If your goal is to modify a configuration file, it can often be helpful to have a file checked into the repository which is a template or set of defaults which can then be copied alongside and modified as appropriate. This second, modified file is usually ignored to prevent accidentally committing it.

So you definitely should not use `git update-index` for this purpose, and you should instead create a template file that you can update with the appropriate paths for the platform, possibly using a script for this purpose.